# Access file link return undefined with Fine Uploader

Tags: json, fine-uploader

I have some problem to access the JSON response after uploadSuccess.

I reused the code shared [here](http://fineuploader.com/#s3-demo).

My complete callback looks like that :

```
        .on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {
            var $fileEl = $(this).fineUploaderS3("getItemByFileId", id),
                $viewBtn = $fileEl.find(".view-btn");


            if (response.success) {
                $viewBtn.show();
                $viewBtn.attr("href", response.tempLink);
                console.log(response.tempLink);
            }
```

The response to the POST is like that :

```
{"tempLink":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/basedrop\/dc79d6aa-2162-4675-8f21-cb17844b885c.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIO43VK2MP3SIA7HQ&Expires=1383657225&Signature=KDt5Xwb9NAQjgFfCdoZBHek4sRI%3D","thumbnailUrl":"https:\/\/s3.amazonaws.com\/basedrop\/dc79d6aa-2162-4675-8f21-cb17844b885c.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIO43VK2MP3SIA7HQ&Expires=1383657225&Signature=KDt5Xwb9NAQjgFfCdoZBHek4sRI%3D"}SUCCESS
```

But I keep getting **undefined** when I try to output the value of **tempLink**.

What do I miss here ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing undefined as the value of tempLink, then your uploadSuccess endpoint is not including this in its response. Take a closer look at the actual response of the uploadSuccess request via Chrome's network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: But as I mentioned previously, the response is OK. I got "tempLink" and "thumbnailUrl". But I can't access it in the callback function. I used s3demo-thumbnails-cors.php like in your demo. You can have a look here : http://drop.baaaaase.com/

Comment: Please don't mind my previous comment, I realized that I forgot to comment out the echo "SUCCESS" line.